# NestJS Typeorm filter relations from reponse

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

How can one ensure only the entity itself and not it's relations are returned by TypeOrm when using `Repository.save(myEntity)`?

given this example entity

```js
@Entity()
export class Flavor {
  @ManyToMany(
    type => Coffee,
    coffee => coffee.flavors,
  )
  coffees: Coffee[];
}
```

```js
@Entity()
export class Coffee {
  @JoinTable()
  @ManyToMany(
    type => Flavor,
    flavor => flavor.coffees,
  )
  flavors: Flavor[];
}
```

and this example service

```js
  async create(createCoffeeDto: CreateCoffeeDto) {
    const flavors = await Promise.all(
      createCoffeeDto.flavors.map(name => this.preloadFlavorByName(name)),
    );

    const coffee = this.coffeeRepository.create({
      ...createCoffeeDto,
      flavors,
    });
    return this.coffeeRepository.save(coffee);
  }
```

how can I filter the response so it only returns the `Coffee` entity and not the `Flavor` entity. Eg ***this***

```json
{
  "id": 0,
  "name": "string",
  "brand": "string",
  "recommendations": 0,
}
```

***not this***

```json
{
  "id": 0,
  "name": "string",
  "brand": "string",
  "recommendations": 0,
  "flavors": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "string",
      "coffees": [
        null
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this would be to use class transformer.
https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer

First you define your response class like this:

```
export class CreateCoffeeResponseDto {
   id: number;
   name: string;
   brand: string;
   recommendations: number;
}
```

And then when returning it from the service you can:

```
return plainToClass(CoffeeCreateResponseDto, await this.coffeeRepository.save(coffee));
```

Also, you can do it all with .save() call if you put { cascade: true } options object on your relations.
https://typeorm.io/#/relations/cascades

Comment: cascade enables implicit updating of relations; using the `class-transformer` gem does work, but I'm wondering if there is some way in TypeORM itself. Eg if the associations are updated I would want to return the updated associations, but if only the primary object is updated I would just want to control that...I basically want more fine grained control over what subset of the associations are returned, because sometimes there may be many nested layers of associations)